# Syntax error in INSERT statement into MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I couldn't find the syntax error in the following INSERT statement.

```
public partial class doRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\database";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (staffID,accessLevelIdD,username,password,email) VALUES (@staffID, '2', @username,@password,@email)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffID", Request.Form["staffid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",Request.Form["confpassword"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Request.Form["username"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Request.Form["email"]);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully registered!");
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `Password` is a [*reserved keyword*](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) in OLE DB Provider. Use it with square brackets like `[Password]`. But as a best practise, change it to *non-reserved* word.

And `OleDbCommand` doesn't support named parameters.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection **must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text**.

In documentation it says **? must be used** but *actually*, it is not. Named parameters *do* work, but the names are irrelevant; it's still the position of the parameters in the `CommandText` and the order in which they are added that matters.

And don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes. Use [`.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Finally, you don't need to close your connection manually with `con.Close()` in your `finally` block because `using` statement automatically handle it.

By the way, I have to say, `accessLevelIdD` column sounds like a numeric type from it's name since it ends with `ID`. If it is (or should or not), you need to pass value as `2` not `'2'`.